# How to get sidemenu based on category id in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, sidemenu

I am working on Porto theme and on Magento -1.9.1 version website

On the homepage, I am getting my category menu at left side. On this page, i want to add subcategory slider section also. For that slider, i want to add that particular category's sub categories. As of now, i added these categories static instead of dynamic. So, My requirement is, How to get the sidemenu based on that particular category id?

My `sidemenu.phtml` code is as follows:

```
<?php $menuHelper = Mage::helper('megamenu'); ?>
<?php $menuData = $menuHelper->getMenuData(); extract($menuData); ?>
<ul class="menu side-menu">
    <?php echo $menuHelper->getMenuContent(); ?>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var SW_MENU_POPUP_WIDTH = <?php echo $_popupWidth; ?>;
jQuery(function($){
    $('.menu.side-menu').et_menu({
        type: "default"
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Like this, I want to add sidemenu for the category sliders which are existed.
So, how to add side menu based on the some category id?